# Why is everything in binary?

Tags: digital-logic

The question is self-evident. Is digital electronics really the most optimal solution? As I continue to learn about half-adders, full adders, multiplexing, etc. I feel like these digital circuits are kind of arbitrary solutions.

They are for sure, a solution, but aren't they just **a** solution? For example, 121 is a 7-bit unsigned integer. If we want to represent it we will need 7 transistors (maybe diodes,) but actually, it would be a 3-bit number if we represented it in base 10. Isn't it cheaper element-wise?

What are the reasons for the wide use of digital circuits? Besides historical reasons.

People say we use binary because it is easier but I don't feel like this is the only reason to justify its use. Maybe reliability is a concern and somehow only digital circuits are reliable.

Were there any attempts in the past for another way to do this?

Comment: So, how many transistors in base 10 are needed to represent decimal 121?

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't use transistors for that one, otherwise, it's just the same. My bad @Andyaka

Comment: One question to ponder: with base 2, there are only two possibilities. It either happens, or it doesn't happen. You can realize a switch controlled by a base-2 value very simply - just something that's on above some threshold, and off below that threshold, or vice versa. We have real-world things (e.g. MOSFETs) that do that perfectly. As soon as you hit base 3, how would you realize a switch that needs to turn on e.g. for 0 and 2 but not 1?

Comment: You can say 0 - 0.5 mA is 0 and 0.5 - 1 mA is 1 and 1-1.5 is 2 and so on. It probably is a dumb suggestion but I'm just stating that it is doable

Comment: So how do you get a simple switch to do 0-0.5A etc? just a switch with two contacts...

Comment: Multiple current levels or voltage levels can be made to work - but they will never work as well as binary.  [Multi-level flash memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) stores data in various voltage levels in single transistors.  You still have to convert the values to binary to use it.  The alternative is to use analog adders to do calculations - with the loss of precision and reliability that goes along with it.

Comment: Multi-level logic is a thing. But it’s more complex to implement than binary. Neuromorphic AI uses a quasi-analog approach.

Comment: You make it sound like people who use base 10 math randomly choose base 2 devices.  And binary must be inferior to decimal devices.  Why?  Because we can count on our fingers.   Boole conceived of boolean algebra in the 1850's, so 100 years later, technology caught up with him.

Comment: Re, "You can say 0 - 0.5 mA is 0 and 0.5 - 1 mA is 1 and 1-1.5 is 2 and so on" Yes, You can say that. But how do you get from that specification to a circuit that can add two of those digits, giving a one digit sum and a one-digit carry? (I don't know the answer, but I believe the folk here who think it would be a lot more complex than a circuit that can add binary numbers in approximately the same range.)

Comment: "You can say 0 - 0.5 mA is 0 and 0.5 - 1 mA is 1 and 1-1.5 is 2 and so on" - Also, in this 'number spectrum', as soon as you connect more and more of this logic together, there will be changes to these currents in parts of these circuits influenced by currents in others parts of the system. How are you gonna account for that or even interpret anything?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question as not opinion-based - as the existing answer illustrates, there's hard math on build complexity using existing technology. There's also hard math on why binary, even if we had other components than transistors, is optimal under some constraints from what we do with computation.

Comment: Noise and thresholds along with component tolerances are the biggest reasons that multiple voltage level digit systems would be hard to implement. If you had several transistors to receive voltage levels the voltage levels would vary widely.

Comment: I am not saying that we should use base 10. I'm saying that since this is a very crucial technology, we should be able to say "for this, this, and this reasons binary numbers are the optimal solution". Otherwise, who knows maybe we are building our systems with %20 less speed and %30 more costs?

Comment: Complexity is a concern. I understand it. Binary is the easiest to work with. I understand that too. However, the easiest solution is almost never the best solution. I'm not saying people started working with binary numbers randomly, there are historical reasons for it. If you want to start somewhere, binary is the most logical place to start because of its simplicity compared to other numbers.

Comment: There's solid math reasoning, aside from very solid technological reasoning (which you try to ignore as "historical", but "80 years of research have not yielded a component that uses less power per computation than a transistor that's either on or off" is a very solid reason.)

Comment: (People like to think of mainstream technology as being unchallenged and "breakthroughs are around the corner if we just let go of mainstream technology", but that's conspiracy theory nonsense – especially in the context of computation. If a useful non-binary computer with properties desirable over binary ones was possible to build, we'd have built it and use it widely – if we need compatibility to the binary world, we could still emulate a binary computer on that. Research has been done and is still massively going on in alternative approaches to computation. So far, our computers are binary)

Comment: This doesn't sound scientific to me. It is too philosophical. You are saying that "we'd have built it and use it widely" by this same logic I should say "there is no need to search for new technology because if there was we would have found it". It is like Lord Kelvin saying there is nothing more to discover

Comment: I would be much happier if I could see some math. About this efficiency thing, maybe you can share some links and publishments that I can read? I'm not here to debate I'm asking this to learn. Because I don't actually claim that "there are better systems than binary". I just want to understand why we are ruling out other possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is binary because it results in the simplest circuits and cheaper computers.

[ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) was built using vacuum tubes.  It used digits as its smallest data size.  Each digit stored a value from 0 to 9.  Each digit used 36 tubes.

You can build a flip-flop to store one bit with two transistors (or two simple tubes.)  For the same 36 tubes, you could build 18 flip-flops to store 18 bits.

That's 0-9 for the ENIAC digit with 36 tubes, or 0-262143 for a binary memory with the same 36 tubes.

Binary wins, hands down, on simplicity and density (transistor utilization.)

Comment: But it's a very old technology. So I guess there weren't any modern attempts to use base 3? Or base whatever

Comment: There's not much point in making newer attempts.  Binary is the most efficient form as long you are using switching elements.  It doesn't matter whether the switching elements are tubes, transistors, diodes, or relays.  Binary makes the best use of them.  Quantum computers will be different, but that's because they don't use switching elements to represent the data.

Comment: @merovingian Just because a technology is old doesn't make it obsolete. An interesting read is how the NTSC television format came to be. Those that came up with our present binary scheme were ahead of their time and didn't realize it. Why don't you try designing a multilevel scheme and make it reliable (ageing, operate over wide temperatures) at GHz clocking speeds. Not a trivial task.

Comment: JRE: thanks for the tube-count for ENIAC's decimal arithmetic - didn't know that. But I should point out that only **one tube** is needed to count in decimal...(DEKATRON) but it is rather specialized for counting. Not efficient in doing arithmetic. Our nervous system is another example where digital pulses merge in an interesting analog-like way.